# communication node with c-Funktion as executable in catkin

Tags: ros, communication, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

**The task**:

I want to create a control for robots via ROS:
I receive data via a callback function (Subscriber) and send directly the calculated outputs in this function (Publisher).
The calculation of the control parameters also needs some additional functions, which are given via other c files.
All this code is given in c.

**The Structure**

```
catkin/src/grampc/

 1. CMakeLists.txt 

 2. package.xml 

 3. include/ (Contains all c++ headerfiles):
    - euler1.h 
    - eulermod2.h 
    - grampc_init.h
    - grampc_mess.h
    - grampc_run.h
    - grampc_setopt.h 
    - grampc_setparam.h
    - heun2.h
    - probfct.h 
    - ruku45.h

 4.  src/ (Contains all c++ sourcefiles):
    - grampc.cpp #<<-- This is the file with the callback function and therefor the node
    - euler1.c 
    - eulermod2.c 
    - grampc_init.c
    - grampc_mess.c 
    - grampc_run.c
    - grampc_setopt.c 
    - grampc_setparam.c
    - heun2.c 
    - probfct.c 
    - ruku45.c

 5.  srv/ (Contains all servicefiles)
    - grampc_IO.srv
```

**The concept:**

So the concept is to build one **executable** (grampc_node with grampc.cpp) which can use functions of other files (euler1.c, euler1.h ....) and that can communicate via a service (grampc_IO).

```
**The Package:**
CMakeLists.txt:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(grampc)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation rosbag)

add_service_files(FILES grampc_IO.srv)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(      CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs rosbag    )

include_directories(include     /include )

#define sources
set(grampc_SRCS
  src/euler1.c
  src/eulermod2.c
  src/heun2.c
  src/probfct.c
  src/ruku45.c
  src/grampc_run.c
  src/grampc_mess.c
  src/grampc_setopt.c
  src/grampc_setparam.c
  src/grampc_init.c
)

#define a grampc_node target
add_executable(grampc_node src/grampc.cpp ${grampc_SRCS})

#now link our node to the library, and all the libraries from the other pkgs
target_link_libraries(grampc_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(grampc_node grampc_gencpp)

install(TARGETS grampc_node RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

package.xml:

```
<package>
  <!-- Package Metadata -->
  <name>grampc</name>
  <version>1.2.4</version>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <!-- Required by Catkin -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
 
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
  <run_depend>rosbag</run_depend>
  <!-- at build time you need message_generation -->
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <!-- at run time you need message_runtime -->
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>

  <!-- Add services -->
 add_service_files(FILES grampc_IO.srv )

</package>
```

**Problem**:
The required source files (which are located in grampc/src) or headerfiles (which are located in grampc/include) are not getting linked or better: I get undefined references. I don't know how to proceed. It would be amazing if you would have any ideas about that.

With the catkin_make grampc to just make the Package:

```
user:~/Workspace/catkin$ catkin_make grampc
Base path: /home/user/Workspace/catkin
    Source space: /home/user/Workspace/catkin/src
    Build space: /home/user/Workspace/catkin/build
    Devel space: /home/user/Workspace/catkin/devel
    Install space: /home/user/Workspace/catkin/install
    ####
    #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/user/Workspace/catkin/build"
    ####
    ####

#### Running command: "make grampc -j4 -l4" in "/home/user/Workspace/catkin/build"
####
```

with the catkin_make command for the whole workspace:

```
...
/home/user/Workspace/catkin/src/grampc/src/grampc.cpp:133:44: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   grampc_setparam_vector(mpc_ws,"xdes",xdes);
                                            ^
/home/user/Workspace/catkin/src/grampc/src/grampc.cpp:134:44: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   grampc_setparam_vector(mpc_ws,"udes",udes);
                                            ^
Linking CXX executable /home/user/Workspace/catkin/devel/lib/grampc/grampc_node
CMakeFiles/grampc_node.dir/src/grampc.cpp.o: In function `grampc_IO_callback(grampc::grampc_IORequest_<std::allocator<void> >&, grampc::grampc_IOResponse_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `grampc_run(typeGRAMPC*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
CMakeFiles/grampc_node.dir/src/grampc.cpp.o: In function `main':
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `grampc_init(typeGRAMPC**)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x477): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_string(typeGRAMPC*, char*, char*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x4a4): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x4d1): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x4ea): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_string(typeGRAMPC*, char*, char*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x517): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x544): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x571): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x59e): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
CMakeFiles/grampc_node.dir/src/grampc.cpp.o:grampc.cpp:(.text+0x5f8): more undefined references to `grampc_setopt_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)' follow
CMakeFiles/grampc_node.dir/src/grampc.cpp.o: In function `main':
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x607): undefined reference to `grampc_printopt(typeGRAMPC*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x631): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x65b): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_real(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x675): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_int(typeGRAMPC*, char*, int)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x690): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x6ab): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x6c5): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_int(typeGRAMPC*, char*, int)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x6e0): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x6fb): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x716): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x731): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to `grampc_setparam_vector(typeGRAMPC*, char*, double*)'
grampc.cpp:(.text+0x75b): undefined reference to `grampc_printparam(typeGRAMPC*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Workspace/catkin/devel/lib/grampc/grampc_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [grampc/CMakeFiles/grampc_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Thanks in Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200939/communication-node-with-c-funktion-as-executable-in-catkin/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-14**:
Did you try naming your header files *.h instead of *.c?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-01-14**:
Are your header files really named ".c" rather than ".h" or ".hpp" or is that an error in your description?

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2015-01-14**:
Sorry my mistake. They have the ending *.h.
I changed it above.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-01-15**:
In principle that should work as you did... Maybe check the code of your files again? Are the functions really defined somewhere in the named src files with exactly the same signature? It appears that all missing refs have a typeGRAMPC pointer? Maybe there are ambiguous declarations of this type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Problem was solved.
The external functions are c-Code.
So you have to refer to them with extern "C"

---

Originally posted by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) with karma: 170 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1